# Convert.ToInt32 works in if statement, but not with ? operator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

For some reason Visual Studio has a problem with this line:

```
MandatoryStakeholder.SupportDocTypeID = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(allIDValues[1]) || (allIDValues[1] == "0")) ?  null : Convert.ToInt32(allIDValues[1]);
```

Specifically the `Convert.ToInt32(allIDValues[1])` part. The error is "C#: These types are not compatible 'null' : 'int'"

However if I emulate that logic with the below it has no issue:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(allIDValues[1]) || Convert.ToInt32(allIDValues[1]) == 0)
                stakeHolder.SupportDocTypeId = null;
            else
                stakeHolder.SupportDocTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(allIDValues[1]);
```

`MandatoryStakeholder.SupportDocTypeID` is of type int?. Not sure why I can convert a string to an int in an if statement, but not with the ? operator.

Comment: I believe a ternary is supposed to have the same return type in both branches. So you need an `int?` that is `null` instead of just `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try casting the `null` to an `int?`

```
MandatoryStakeholder.SupportDocTypeID = 
    (String.IsNullOrEmpty(allIDValues[1]) || (allIDValues[1] == "0")) ?  
       (int?)null : 
       Convert.ToInt32(allIDValues[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the `? null` to `? (int?) null`.

```
MandatoryStakeholder.SupportDocTypeID = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(allIDValues[1]) || (allIDValues[1] == "0")) ?  (int?)null : Convert.ToInt32(allIDValues[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because in the if version,

```
 stakeHolder.SupportDocTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(allIDValues[1]);
```

is silently being converted to

```
 stakeHolder.SupportDocTypeId = new int?(Convert.ToInt32(allIDValues[1]));
```

To get the ternary equivalent, you'll need to change your code to:

```
MandatoryStakeholder.SupportDocTypeID = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(allIDValues[1]) || (allIDValues[1] == "0")) ?  null : new int?(Convert.ToInt32(allIDValues[1]));
```